# Keep header div always above others

Tags: html, css

Struggling a bit with HTML positioning. I'm sure it's a pretty simple problem, but just can't crack it.

Please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HMyXW/2/

Basically, I am trying to position the yellow div (`#logo`) above everything else, so it will push any other content on the page down, even if the screen is resized vertically.

I've tried messing with z-positions, etc. but am not having much luck.

Comment: Is that position:absolute and fixed are really necessary?? Cant you try with relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest remove all the `fixed positions` if it is not necessary and add a outer div to wrap all the child divs.

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HMyXW/4/)**

---

If it is necessary to use the `position:fixed` to the `#logo` then you need to check the height of the `#logo` and give the same value as `margin-top` to the content div.

Answer (score 1):

Your #logo has `position: fixed;` which means the element is removed from the normal page flow.